# Java error class, interface expected

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I imported an Eclipse project to Android Studio. All is fine but I see some errors in a Java file. Maybe the code is wrong. I tried fixing this for hours but still no luck. What is wrong and how to fix this?

```
package com.newgame.gdx;


// Referenced classes of package com.newgame.gdx:
//            Application

public static final class  extends Enum
{
    private static final  iOS $VALUES[];
    public static final iOS Android;
    public static final iOS Applet;
    public static final iOS Desktop;
    public static final iOS HeadlessDesktop;
    public static final iOS WebGL;
    public static final iOS iOS;
    public static  valueOf(String s)
    {
        return ()Enum.valueOf(com/newgame/gdx/Application$ApplicationType, s);
    }
    public static [] values()
    {
        return ([])$VALUES.clone();
    }
    static 
    {
        Android = new <init>("Android", 0);
        Desktop = new <init>("Desktop", 1);
        HeadlessDesktop = new <init>("HeadlessDesktop", 2);
        Applet = new <init>("Applet", 3);
        WebGL = new <init>("WebGL", 4);
        iOS = new <init>("iOS", 5);
        $VALUES = (new .VALUES[] {
            Android, Desktop, HeadlessDesktop, Applet, WebGL, iOS
        });
    }
private (String s, int i)
    {
        super(s, i);
    }
}
```

Comment: error show in each line class or interface expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was mentioned earlier, you should name your class. But this is not the only problem with your code.

First of all, **static** modifier is not allowed in top-level classes.
This keyword points to the fact that an instance of the class can stand on its own: unlike a non-static inner class (instance inner class) which cannot exist without an instance of the outer class, a top-level class does not have an outer class, it can't be anything but static. As you can see, they are static by default, so there's no point in such modifier to be explicitly announced.

Second, you definitely shouldn't and **couldn't** subclass Enum: they are essentially converted to a final class by compiler and therefore no inheritance allowed. Also extending confronts the whole idea of Enums: each enum type should have only the elements declared in the enum (so you can use them in a **switch** statements, for example), and this is not possible if you allow extending the type.

If you're for some reason **need** to imitate enum extending, you may try something like [this](http://blog.pengyifan.com/how-to-extend-enum-in-java/).
But I'm still not sure this is the right way to design your functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Enum` has no name. It should look something like:

```
public final class MyEnum extends Enum
{
```

Judging from the contents, it should be name something like a `Platform`.

Comment: Is this decompiled code, by any chance? Can you try to use the name `iOS` instead of `Platform`?

Comment: ya this is decompiled code, im new to development can you tell me how to fix this by simple way?